# Simplest way to promote successful online TFS builld to production - Azure

Tags: azure, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-web-roles

Firstly, apologies that the question is not strictly about programming, but how to simply promote an Azure website through environments. If anyone can suggest a better place for this question to be posted then please fee free.

**Scenario**

I have a two Azure website environments.  Lets call them:

- www.myTestSite.com
- www.myProductionSite.com

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and am using TFS on Visual Studio Online.

I have managed to configure everything to the point where I can check in to TFS and on a successful build, automatically deploy to www.myTestSite.com.

The files are saved in a 'Drops' folder on Visual Studio Online (TFS).  It all works great up to this point.

**What is the simplest way of then taking one of these successful builds and promoting it to www.myProductionSite.com?**

Comment: Why don't you create a copy of the Test Build and call it Production Build and trigger it when ever you are happy with Test Build? or you can create a production branch of code and Deploy the site to Production site (Gated Check in).

Comment: Thanks Suresh.  On option one, I have been thinking about that. Would I need to get a specific version from TFS to my local machine and then trigger the production build or is there another way.  Sorry, out of my comfort zone here :)

Comment: I am not asking you to create a production branch of code in your machine. :-) Use Two different set of codes. Lets Say Main And Dev. Always work with dev Branch which is branched from Main. Once you are happy with dev branch Merge it back to Main branch. Trigger the Build When ever code is merged to Main branch to  Production server. Hope it make sense. You can enable Gated check in the Main Branch. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787631.aspx

Comment: Thanks again.  Yes it does make sense. I'll look at branching.  I have a gated check in at the moment so I understand that part.